# Why $[K:\Bbb{Q}]\leq2\dim A$ holds for CM abelian variety?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties, complex-multiplication

Let $A$ be an abelian variety. Let $K$ be a CM field.
${\rm End}^0(A):={\rm End}(A)\otimes_{\Bbb{Z}}\Bbb{Q} $.
$A$ is said to have CM by $K$ if only if ${\rm End}^0(A)$ contains $K$.

Then, **why $[K:\Bbb{Q}]\leq2\dim A$ holds** ?

This maybe famous fact as though I couldn't find the statement exactly.
To be honestly,I don't understand why $K$ should be CM field except for the case of CM elliptic curves. Reference only is also appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I realize that we can show it with $A[n] \cong \Bbb{Z}/(n)^{2d}$ and some algebraic number theory result. If $End^0(A)$ contains a field $K$ then there is a primitive element $b\in End(A)$ such that $K=\Bbb{Q}(b)$.
The minimal polynomial $f\in \Bbb{Z}[x]$ of $b$ is irreducible $\bmod n$ for some $n$ (coprime with the leading coefficient), with which I mean that  $f\not \equiv gh\bmod n$ with $g,h\in \Bbb{Z}[x]$ non-constant whose leading coefficient is a unit $\bmod n$.
Clearly the minimal polynomial of $b|_{A[n]}$ has degree $\le 2d$. So $[K:\Bbb{Q}]=\deg(f)\le 2d$.

---

There is certainly an abstract algebra argument, but it is worth knowing that it becomes evident on the complex torus side.

Let $A=\Bbb{C}^d/ \Lambda$ be a complex torus.

$End(A)$ is the space of $\Bbb{C}$-linear maps $h:\Bbb{C}^d\to \Bbb{C}^d$ such that $h(\Lambda)\subset \Lambda$.

If $End(A)\otimes_\Bbb{Z}\Bbb{Q}$ contains a field $K$ then by the primitive element theorem $K = \Bbb{Q}(b)$ for some $b\in End(A)$.

Let $\tilde{b} = b|_\Lambda \in End_\Bbb{Z}(\Lambda)$.

$\Lambda \cong \Bbb{Z}^{2d}$ so the minimal polynomial $f\in \Bbb{Z}[x]$ of $\tilde{b}$ has degree $\le 2d$.

$\Bbb{C}^d = \Lambda \otimes_\Bbb{Z}\Bbb{R}$ so $f(b)=0\in End(A)$ and $[K:\Bbb{Q}]\le \deg(f)\le 2d$.

Comment: Thank you so much. May I ask there questions ?  $1.$ What is your motivation to consider $b \mid_Λ$ instead of $b$ itself ?  $2.$ Why $f(\tilde b)=0$ implies $f(b)=0$ ? $3.$ Why degree of minimal polynomial of $\tilde b$ is less than $2dimA$ ?  For $3.$, I think discriminant of $d×d$ matrix should relate, because I encountered such an argument in CM elliptic curve case...but don't understand what is the essential difference between $d=1$ case and $d≧2$ case...

Comment: @topology: Everything boils down to the fact that you have an embedding $K^\times\hookrightarrow{\rm GL}_{2d}(\mathbb{Q})$ and so you use the fact that every matrix in ${\rm GL}_{N}(L)$ (where $L$ is any field) satisfies a polynomial relation of degree $\leq N$ with coefficients in $L$.

Comment: @topology: as reuns pointed out the endomorphisms of $A$ lift to linear maps of $\mathbb{C}^d$ that send the lattice $\Lambda\simeq\mathbb{Z}^{2d}$ to itself. Therefore you get a map from $K={\rm End}(A)\otimes\mathbb{Q}$ to ${\rm End}_{\mathbb Q}(\Lambda\otimes\mathbb{Q})\simeq{\rm Mat}_{2d}(\mathbb{Q})$ which is obviously injective. Also note that a nonzero element in $K$ is invertible, so must be the corresponding matrix (in fact this is not relevant for the conclusion). This is just a clarification of the answer we're commenting so there's no need for upgrading it to a new answer.

Comment: @reuns. I don't understand why you need to restrict $b$ to $Λ$. Without doing such a thing, we can make homomorphism from $End(E)$ to $M_2(\Bbb{Z})$ by fixing basis, and deg(minimal polynomial of $b$)=deg(minimal polynomial of $2d×2d$ matrix)$≦2d$, I think.

Comment: @Andrea Mori. $K=End(A)\otimes \Bbb{Q}$ is false. But your comments are really helpful, thank you.

Comment: @topology: sorry, that was a typo: $K\subset{\rm End}(A)\otimes\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Andrea Mori  what do you think about my last comment to reuns ?

Comment: @topology It is unclear what you mean with fixing a basis. The basis $c_j$ should be one of $\Lambda$ so that $f\in End(E)$ sends $\sum_j c_j \Bbb{Z}$ to itself which gives that its characteristic polynomial is in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$. Without using that $b\in End(E)$ sends $\Lambda$ to itself, all you can say is that the characteristic/minimal polynomial will be in $\Bbb{C}[x]$ or $\Bbb{R}[x]$...